# How to list IAM policies attached to an AWS IoT Thing certificate with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-iot

I need to get a list of the IAM policies attached to an AWS IoT Thing's certificate, in way that is script/automation-friendly. I have searched through the documentation website and the man pages, but didn't find a command that seemed to achieve this (e.g.: **aws iot describe-certificate** does not include this in it output).

Is there a way to achieve this with the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 1):

You can get thing's certificate and policy attached to that certificate by running the following two commands of AWS CLI:

- `aws iot list-thing-principals --thing-name [Name of your IoT Thing]`. This command will return the **Certificate ARN** attached to your thing.
- `aws iot list-principal-policies --principal [Certificate ARN]`. This command will return the **policies** attached to the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you actually mean IoT policies. Use the list-principal-policies api call to list the IoT policies attached to a certificate.